# Including an event-based model in a unit test

Tags: c#, .net, moq, xunit

I'm new to C# and .NET development and I'm testing out a method from `ThingEventService.cs`.

`ThingUpdatedEvent.cs` is included in the service file and I'm trying to include it in the test, but I'm having trouble with 1. Ensuring that it's recognized by the test, and 2. Determining what I need to provide in order for it to be included properly.

I'm running into the following error:

> Models/ThingUpdatedEvent.cs(12,15): error CS1729: 'object' does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments

, which is pointing to the `: base()` line that I've included in `ThingUpdatedEvent.cs`.

If I remove the following from the test:

```cs
ThingUpdatedEvent request = new ThingUpdatedEvent
   (updateRequest, thingBeforeUpdate, thingAfterUpdate)
   {
     UpdateRequest = UpdateThingRequest,
     ThingBeforeUpdate = ThingBeforeUpdate,
     ThingAfterUpdate = ThingAfterUpdate
   };
            
   await this._svc.HandleThingUpdatedAsync(request);
```

then the test runs, but I'm getting a `Moq.Mockexception` error stating that it "Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times". It's led me to think that I *need* to include `ThingUpdatedEvent` in order for the test to run and pass.

---

#### Questions:

- Do I need to include `ThingUpdatedEvent` in the test?

  - If not, what could be causing the invocation to not run?
- Is `:base ()` allowed on event-based models?

---

---

#### ThingUpdatedEvent.cs

```cs
namespace someFolder.someOtherFolder.etc
{
    public class ThingUpdatedEvent
    {
        public ThingUpdatedEvent(
            [NotNull] UpdateThingRequest updateRequest,
            [NotNull] Thing thingBeforeUpdate,
            [NotNull] Thing thingAfterUpdate) 
            : base(updateRequest, thingBeforeUpdate, thingAfterUpdate) // is base:() necessary for this?
        {
            this.UpdateRequest = updateRequest;
            this.ThingBeforeUpdate = thingBeforeUpdate;
            this.ThingAfterUpdate = thingAfterUpdate;
        }

        [NotNull]
        public UpdateThingRequest UpdateRequest { get; set; }

        [NotNull]
        public Thing ThingBeforeUpdate { get; set; }

        [NotNull]
        public Thing ThingAfterUpdate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

#### ThingEventServiceTests.cs

```cs
     public class ThingEventServiceTests
     {
        Mock<IAuditLog> _auditLog;
        Mock<AuditHelper> _auditHelper;
        ThingEventService _svc;

        public ThingEventServiceTests()
        {
            this._auditLog = new Mock<IAuditLog>();
            this._auditHelper = new Mock<AuditHelper>();
            this._svc = new ThingEventService(
                Mock.Of<IAEService>(),
                this._auditLog.Object);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task CanHandleThingUpdatedAsync()
        {
            var SourceEntities = new List<AEModel>
            { 
                AETypes.System.Create("Things") 
            };
            
            ThingUpdatedEvent request = new ThingUpdatedEvent
            (updateRequest, thingBeforeUpdate, thingAfterUpdate)
            {
                UpdateRequest = UpdateThingRequest,
                ThingBeforeUpdate = ThingBeforeUpdate,
                ThingAfterUpdate = ThingAfterUpdate
            };
            
            await this._svc.HandleThingUpdatedAsync(request);

            It.IsAny<IEnumerable<AEModel>>();
            this._auditLog.Verify(m => m.RecordEventAsync(
                "123435",
                "requester",
                SourceEntities,
                AuditEventTypes.ThingEdited,
                "Thing edited",
                "Thing was edited: Some Title",
                It.IsAny<IEnumerable<FieldChange>>(),
                It.IsAny<IEnumerable<string>>(),
                It.IsAny<IEnumerable<Tag>>(),
                null,
                null,
                null
                ), Times.Once);
        }
  }
```

---

#### ThingEventService.cs

```cs
public async task HandleThingUpdatedAsync(ThingUpdatedEvent evt)
{

            // if (condition)
            {
                IEnumerable<AEModel> defaultSourceEntities = await this._auditHelper
                    .GetDefaultSourceEntitiesForThingEventAsync(evt.ThingAfterUpdate);
                Task auditLogEditTask = this._auditLog.RecordEventAsync(
                    id: evt.ThingAfterUpdate.Id.ToString(),
                    user: evt.UpdateRequest.Requester,
                    sourceEntities: defaultSourceEntities,
                    eventType: AuditEventTypes.ThingEdited,
                    title: "Thing edited",
                    description: $"Thing was edited: {evt.ThingAfterUpdate.Title} (ID: {evt.ThingAfterUpdate.Id})",
                    fieldChanges: fieldChanges,
                    comments: null,
                    tags: this._auditHelper.GetDefaultTagsForThing(evt.ThingAfterUpdate));
                tasks.Add(auditLogEditTask);
            }

}
```

Comment: Is that the real code? ThingUpdatedEvent has no base class so calling base from the constructor can't work. And in the test you seem to create that class setting things via the constructor and via an initializer (so you try to do it twice).

Answer (score 0):

Update: I was able to do

```cs
        [Fact]
        public async Task CanHandleThingUpdatedAsync()
        {

            UpdateThingRequest updateThingRequest = new UpdateThingRequest(
                something: "something",
                etc: "etc"
            );

            Thing thingBeforeUpdateRequest = new Thing
            {
                Name = "Paper Pusher"
            };

            Thing thingAfterUpdateRequest = new Thing
            {
                Name = "Paper Flinger"
            };

            ThingUpdatedEvent request = new ThingUpdatedEvent(updateThingRequest, thingBeforeUpdateRequest, thingAfterUpdateRequest);
            
            await this._svc.HandleThingUpdatedAsync(request);

// etc
```

without having to update `ThingUpdatedEvent.cs`. Thanks @ralf for pointing out the issue with the base class and for steering me in the right direction.